# JAVA OPTS Xms Xmx MetaspaceSize MaxMetaspaceSize relationship with server resources

Tags: java, cpu, out-of-memory, resources, jboss

I have just started working with jboss application servers and recently we had a problem when trying to deploy an application in a new test server (RHEL 7), it happened that, when starting the jboss service (jboss eap 7.1) with the application in the deployment area, the server began to freeze, that is, it began to respond extremely slowly and it was necessary to turn it off, we solved the problem simply by adding more cpu and ram, in the configuration (`standalone.conf`) there are these parameters:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
```

Could you give me a brief explanation of the meaning of each one and its relationship with the memory and cpu of the server? Is there any rule or recommendation to take into account to configure these parameters and server resources?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html) and [here](http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/link/has_v101001/0342111De/0799.HTM) you can find sample reference what `java` parameters are about.

> The -Xms option sets the initial and minimum Java heap size.
> -Xmx - This option sets the maximum Java heap size.
> -XX:MetaspaceSize specifies the standard value for full GCs that originate in the
> Metaspace area

and so on.

What to set depend on your application and your hardware.